# When to invalidate cache - .net core api

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, api-design

How do I know when to invalidate the cache, if a table change is made from an outside source?

I have an api call that returns an employee table. The first time this call is made, I will cache the results so that on subsequent calls it will pull the data from the cache instead of the database. This makes sense, however, what happens if someone adds a new record to the employee table from **outside of the api**, how does the cache know that it is now invalid?

If the user made the change to the employee table *through the API* I can capture that, but we have a separate desktop app that doesn't use the API, and that app can directly make changes to the employee table. Is there any accepted standards for handling this?

The only possible solution I can think of is to add a trigger to the employee table, and somehow use that to know when a table has changed. But, we have over a thousand tables, and we are making an api call for each table - So, I do not think that adding a thousand triggers to our database is an acceptable solution.

Comment: Is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server available in core?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could add a trigger as suggested. Or you could use a caching system that support expiry time/sliding expiry. So you would be serving up stale data some of the time but not always.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer a suggests your trigger idea is ok, however as you've stated that would be a lot of triggers.

If your cache is not local to the API, which i assume it isn't if triggers would be able to access. Could you not access it from your desktop application? You could invalidate your cache by removing the employee record from the cache with the desktop application when it makes a successful change to the employee table.

It boils down to..

You have a cache (which is essentially a read store).
You have two options to update it 
- Either it times out and fetches (which is ok, if you dont need up to the minute real time data)
- Or is *has* to be told its data is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this

1. Push model
2. Pull model

**Push Model:** Using a database trigger for SQL server table to populate an intermediate audit table and polling that using a background task.

**Pull Model:** Using [CLR Trigger](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-clr-triggers-in-c-sharp-and-install-and-uninstall-clr-assembly-in-mssql/) and pushing the updates to an API. Whenever DML happens the CLR trigger will call the Api, qhich in-turn can update the cache!

Hope this helps!